# Simple Java WebService Client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, axis

I've just started building my first web-service application, by following the eclipse toutorial : http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Implementing_a_Simple_Web_Service.pdf

After that I wanted to build web-service client using axis.jar. To create web-service client I have to add "web app library" at build path to get rid of this error:

```
"The type javax.xml.rpc.Call cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".
```

Now is my quiestion : Is it possible to create web service client without adding this web app library? In my client code I want to set only a WSDL path.
Thank you in advance

Comment: [JAX-WS : wsgen tool example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsgen-tool-example/), [JAX-WS @WebService example](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/) and [JAX-WS Five Minute Tutorial | Javalobby](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world).

Comment: It looks like your webapp is missing some required jars from WEB-INF/lib; in particular the jaxrpc jar.